# Jest with 'npm test' fails with "Use of const in strict mode"

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I am just trying to use Jest as unit testing framework.
I done and example from official [ReactJS side](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#content).

```
function sum(value1, value2) {
  return value1 + value2;
}
module.exports = sum;
----------------------------------------------------------------
jest.dontMock('../sum');

describe('sum', function() {
 it('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', function() {
   var sum = require('../sum');
   expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
 });
});
```

But when I run npm tests I got next error:

```
/home/app.local/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:12
const fs = require('fs');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

What is going wrong ?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: Node version is v0.10.25

Answer (score 8):

If you read the documentation of the link that you posted, you can see that it says the following:

> Jest uses ES2015 features and requires a Node.js version of at least 4.0.0 to run.

You are on version `0.10.25` which is probably why you are having issues. Upgrading your version to >= 4.0.0 should fix this.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I have missed this requirement.

Comment: Np, hope you get it sorted out.

Comment: If you installed with brew you can just run $ brew upgrade node